# How to select data by using JSON Extract Scalar?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i want to extract `20230024` from the following strings

> [{\"vendorExternalId\": \"459162\", \"isActive\": 1, \"name\": \"Strings1\"}, {\"vendorExternalId\": \"**20230024**\", \"isActive\": 1, \"name\": \"Strings2\"}]

attached is my query in bigquery

```
    select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(teks,"$[vendorExternalID]") as output
from(
select "[{\"vendorExternalId\": \"459162\", \"isActive\": 1, \"name\": \"Strings1\"}, {\"vendorExternalId\": \"20230024\", \"isActive\": 1, \"name\": \"Strings2\"}]" as teks
)
```

my query returned `JSONPath parse error at: [vendorExternalID]`

how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery JSON extract functions don't support the * (star) operator hence you cannot extract arrays. For this you need to create User Defined Functions and parse the JSON into the arbitrary format.

as you see in the below example this returns

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<vendorExternalId INT64, isActive INT64, name STRING>>
```

as

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parseJson(libs STRING)
    RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<vendorExternalId INT64, isActive INT64, name STRING>>
    LANGUAGE js AS """
      try {
        return JSON.parse(libs);
      } catch (e) {
        return [];
      }
    """;
SELECT parseJson('[{\"vendorExternalId\": \"459162\", \"isActive\": 1, \"name\": \"Strings1\"}, {\"vendorExternalId\": \"20230024\", \"isActive\": 1, \"name\": \"Strings2\"}]') parsed
```

you can further `UNNEST` the array

[image]